# How to compare two integer fields in a model method in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, compare, class-method

I want to compare two integer fields inside a method in a django model.
The two fields are not correctly getting compared and it is throwing an error
for example:

```
    total_slots = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="Total number of vehicle slots available for allocation.")
    allocated_slots = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                          validators=[
                                              MaxValueValidator(total_slots),
                                              MinValueValidator(0)
                                          ], )

    def available_slots_left(self):
    if self.allocated_slots < self.total_slots:
        return True
    return False
```

I tried to just simply do this:

```
    def available_slots_left(self):
    if self.allocated_slots < self.total_slots:
        return True
    return False
```

but it didn't work and it returned this error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'IntegerField' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in your method but rather your validator, specifically `MaxValueValidator(total_slots)` won't work because `MaxValueValidator` needs to be passed an **integer** and not a model field. If you do want to set up some validation for that you can create a [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) for it:

```py
from django.db import models


class YourModel(models.Model):
    total_slots = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="Total number of vehicle slots available for allocation.")
    allocated_slots = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], )
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(allocated_slots__lte=models.F("total_slots")),
                name="allocated_slots_lte_total_slots",
            )
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is conducted in the MaxValueValidator, this validator only receives integers but in that case you pass a model field. You can use several methods to implement this validation.

Add this method in your model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.allocated_slots > self.total_slots:
        raise ValidationError("Your error message")
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can use this clean method in that case you have to call the `full_clean()` method before save.

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.allocated_slots > self.total_slots:
        raise ValidationError("Your error message")
```